# Posting a resource with ManyToOne relationship

Tags: spring, rest, post, spring-restcontroller, many-to-one

This question is primarily on How to design a rest API and whats the best practice. I am trying to figure out REST endpoint for `POST` service, consider below sample code:

```
class Person {
    String name;
    @OneToMany
    List<Address> addresses;
}

class Address {
    String someAttribute;
    @ManyToOne
    Person person;
}
```

To add a new `Address` the rest endpoint could look like `POST api/**v1**/address`. The main problem is with the `RequestBody` since we will only have the `id` of `Person` so we need to pass the json like below:

```
{
    "someAttribute": "someValue"
    "personId": 1
}
```

And in `Controller` method, we can't simply use `@RequestBody Address address` as parameter to Rest endpoint method as we do not have `personId` in `Address` class.

I would like to understand whats the best practice here and how should the Rest endpoint be?

PS: Above code is a dummy code just to explain question easily.

## update

to avoid confusion I have updated endpoint url.

Comment: in the `api/1/address`  does the number 1 refers to the person WITH `ID = 1`

Comment: @SpringerF `1` is api version.

Comment: so here you've to pass the id as path param and send adress corectly , otherwise if you want to respect the schema you have to send the person as object inside adress (grab all person info as person key )

Answer (score 0):

Please go through [@PathVariables](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/PathVariable.html) annotations in Spring API .

Using [@PathVariables](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/PathVariable.html) you get the person_id and address_id from URL.

**Creates a person (initially with n address)**

```
POST api/{api_version}/person
```

**Updates a person (only update Person details not address)**

```
PUT api/{api_version}/person/{person_id}
```

**Add a new address to person**

```
POST api/{api_version}/person/{person_id}/addresses
```

**Updates an existing person address**

```
PUT api/{api_version}/person/{person_id}/addresses/{address_id}
```

**Class Structure**

```
class Address {
    Integer id; 
    String someAttribute;
}
class Person {
    Long id;
    String name;
    @OneToMany
    List<Address> addresses;
}
```

**Sample Resource Implementation**

```
@RequestMapping(value="api/{api_version}/person/{person_id}/addresses/{address_id}", method = RequestMethod.PUT)

public ResponseEntity<ApiCustomResponse> updateAddress(
@PathVariable("person_id") Long person_id,
@PathVariable("address_id") Integer address_id, @RequestBody Address address) {

...

}
```